# Creating a view programmatically with frame based on another view created in Storyboard with Auto-layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, ios-autolayout

I have added a Scroll View in Storyboard and set its autolayout properties in Storyboard. So obviously it takes different sizes on different iPhones which is what I want. Now I want to add two subviews in the Scroll View, each take the whole visible region of Scroll View and paging is enabled. So at any point in time one of the subviews is visible and you can swipe left or right to see the other subview.

My problem is, since I am creating these two views in program, I am not sure where I am supposed to set the subviews frames. This is what I am doing now, in viewDidLayoutSubviews, but ideally I would like to do this in viewDidload, but in viewDidLoad the frame is not set yet:

```
@interface ViewController () 
   @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
   @property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *pageOne;
   @property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *pageTwo;
@end

- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews

{
    self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    self.pageOne = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.scrollView.bounds.size.width, self.scrollView.bounds.size.height)];
self.pageOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.pageOne];

    self.pageTwo = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(self.scrollView.bounds.size.width, 0, self.scrollView.bounds.size.width, self.scrollView.bounds.size.height)];
    self.pageTwo.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.pageTwo];


    self.statsScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.bounds.size.width * 2, self.scrollView.bounds.size.height);
}
```

So, my question is, if views I am creating in program (pageOne and pageTwo above) are referring to frame of a view set in Storyboard with auto layout for their sizes, where should I set the code. I know my code has the problem of being executed multiple times which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wait until the actual layouting is finished before you can grab the frame, so `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is a good choice. If you want to make sure the pages are only added once, you can simply include a check if they have already been initialized before, like so:

```
if (!self.pageOne) {
    self.pageOne = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.scrollView.bounds.size.width, self.scrollView.bounds.size.height)];
    self.pageOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.pageOne];
}
```

Of course, you could also initialize the pages in your `viewDidLoad`-method with a CGRectZero frame and add them as subviews, and then set the proper frames later on, i.e.:

**In `viewDidLoad`:**

```
self.pageOne = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
self.pageOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.pageOne];
```

**In `viewDidLayoutSubviews`:**

```
self.pageOne.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.scrollView.bounds.size.width, self.scrollView.bounds.size.height);
```

Comment: The first solution does not work, because viewDidLayoutSubviews is called several times and the first time that it's called there is no guarantee that self.scrollView.bounds has its final value and in fact for my case it did not, therefore the first solution would fix self.pageOne frame to a value that is not correct. But the second solution worked. Thanks.